Why does a `std::vector` not keep the capacity on the heap?
In C++, a std::vector<T> is usually implemented (ignoring the allocator) with the following data members:
template<typename T>
class vector {
  T* ptr_ = nullptr;
  size_t size = 0;
  size_t capacity = 0;
  // ...
};

which means that sizeof(vector) == 24. Given that the capacity is rarely accessed, wouldn't it make sense to keep it in the heap allocated part so that sizeof(vector) == 16? Is this just kept for ABI compatibility reasons?
You could even put the size on the heap, which would make a vector cheaper to move, although the size would become more expensive to access. I can see the argument that it's a tradeoff here, but for the capacity it seems pretty clear-cut.

"Given that the capacity is rarely accessed" - why do you think so ? It is e.g. accessed for every push_back to check if realloc should be done. Also an object of size 24 or similar is quite small anyway.

Placing the size and/or the capacity on the heap would make the class itself smaller but adds a level of indirection and I personally don't think that having one or two more members of size_t is usually noticeable as a waste of automatic memory.

"although the size would become more expensive to access" -- Why do you think this is a bigger concern than accessing the capacity?

"which would make a vector cheaper to move" - and (maybe) more expensive to copy. Copying two members might be faster than copying two values from somewhere on the heap with the added indirection.

I would answer because the vector library was developed by very smart software engineers, they estimated, benchmarked all thin cases while you think about only sizeof(vector).

Related: Why the libc++ std::vector internally keeps three pointers instead of one pointer and two sizes? (By the way, this kind of disputes the question's claimed "usually implemented".)

If you make capacity size_t *, then you just increase the memory footprint of the vector. size_t is a synonym for uintptr_t on most platforms. So the size of the vector would remain the same, but you have an extra few bytes allocated on the heap for no benefit.

"why xyz" questions are actually off-topic, since they are open-ended and opinion based.

@Dunes I think OP would want to store the size and capacity in the same allocated memory as the data, so only use one pointer.

In C++, a std::vector is usually implemented ehr.. no. Who gave you that idea?

On such matters of taste, I  like to trust the experience of giants rather than just my intuition. But still, my guts tell me that size and capacity of a vector are far more frequently used than OP imagines. Just take simple for or foreach on the elements as the primary use case: size/end must be sampled.push_back and resize are the next frequent actions that need capacity. So, I'd rather not waste cpu clocks on extra indirections on them. A good implementation however might rely on allocator_traits members for size optimization: size_type and difference_type are important ones.

"Given that capacity is rarely accessed ..."   Completely false premise.   Every operation that, even potentially, resizes the vector needs to check the capacity and be able to change the capacity.     While there are use cases that don't resize a vector after creating it, there are a significant number of use cases that do resize the vector.

Your question seems to be based on the premise that you could implement std::vector  better than the one in your standard library.  And the evidence you provide is "it seems pretty clear-cut".  The reason the standard library doesn't do what you suggest is because "it seems" is not a sufficient argument for design decisions in the standard library.  Actual measurements are made.
